# Change style of parent element using ng-if directive in child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am new to angular js. Depending on the conditions, I change the background of the cells. But I'll be more than just happy if I can to change the background of the entire line.
 
Here is an example of the code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Status
            </td>
            <td>
                Time waiting
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredAgentsDetailedArr">
            <td ng-if="item.name == 'Not Logged'">
                {{ item.name }}
            </td>
            <td ng-if="item.name == 'In Call'" 
                ng-style="{backgroundColor: 'green'}">
                {{ item.name }}
            </td>
            <td ng-if="item.name == 'Waiting'" 
                ng-style="{backgroundColor: 'red'}">
                {{ item.name }}
            </td>

           <td ng-if="item.time_waiting[6] < 3 && item.time_waiting[4] == 0" 
               ng-style="{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}">
               {{ item.time_waiting }}
           </td>
           <td ng-if="item.time_waiting[6] >= 3 && item.time_waiting[4] < 2 ||
                      item.time_waiting[4] == 1 && item.time_waiting[3] == 0"
               ng-style="{backgroundColor: 'gold'}">
               {{ item.time_waiting }}
           <td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That is, everything works. But I'd like to add a style(or maybe ng-class) to the entire string and not to one cell. Maybe someone knows how this can be implemented using the ng-if directive?
Thank you in advance!)

Comment: if you are learning angular why dont you try the lastest version?... in september the will realise a new version ..angular 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Your html

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Status
        </td>
        <td>
            Time waiting
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredAgentsDetailedArr"
        ng-class="{ 'incall' : item.name == 'In Call', 'waiting' : item.name == 'Waiting'}">
        <td ng-if="item.name == 'Not Logged'">
            {{ item.name }}
        </td>
        <td ng-if="item.name == 'In Call'">
            {{ item.name }}
        </td>
        <td ng-if="item.name == 'Waiting'">
            {{ item.name }}
        </td>

       <td >
         <span ng-if="item.time_waiting[6] < 3 && item.time_waiting[4] == 0"
               ng-style="{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}">
           {{ item.time_waiting }}
         </span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

On your css

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.incall {
  background-color: green;
}

.waiting {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Alejandro Alvarado, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need!)

Answer (score 0):

Conditional styling is done using the `ng-class` or the `ng-style` directives.

Plase, take a look at the oficial documentation: [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).